# Send a parameters to self page with link and get it without page refresh in php

Tags: php

I want a page (showmarker.php) that It is used in Google Maps and Markers:

```
marker.set("type", "point");
    marker.set("id", c);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, c) {
        return function() {
            window.location.href = "showmarker.php?location=" + c; 
            canter=myLatLng;
        }
    })(marker, c));
```

this function active with click on each marker.I want send c parameter to showmarker.php without page refresh and get it with php.Please Help me...

Comment: "without page refresh" … so why are you setting `location.href`?!

Comment: The search term you're looking for is "AJAX".  Using AJAX, your JavaScript code can send requests to server-side resources (pages) and read those responses without refreshing the page.